# How to Send Selected File from android to javascript in Webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I want to send selected file's (stream) from android to javascript which is in Webview to show file in Html.

For showing preview of selected files.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: You want to preview the file without uploading it ?

Comment: Yes I  want to preview the file